# Configure different file_ignore_patterns in telescope

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

I have a file (`NAMESPACE`), that I want to ignore during live_grep, but I want to show it with the file browser. Currently I have the following in my lua.init.

```
require("telescope").setup{defaults = { file_ignore_patterns= {"**NAMESPACE", "^.git"}}}
```

Is it possible to ignore the file_ignore_pattern for the file browser? I tried

```
keymap('n', '<leader>fb', '<cmd>lua require("telescope.builtin").file_browser({hidden=true, no_ignore = true, file_ignore_pattern = {}})<cr>', opts)
```

but it is not working.